# Anyone know Yahoo Messenger Http Request?

Tags: yahoo

see yahoo messenger client can running in http request mode and their webmessenger do the same, have anyone know details about "this protocol", login request, send message request, receive message etc..., thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look at how http://www.pidgin.im/ is doing it. There should be a library with all the code used for working with yahoo there. 
You might want to use their libpurple ( http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple ) library, as its free and i guess easy to use(never used it though)

Comment: i'd have upvoted this answer if you didn't say "i guess it's easy but i've never tried" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark to study the protocol. Although, I think that there must be something about this on the internet.. have you google for yahoo messenger web protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/chapterintrotomessengersdk.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library of **IM SDK Yahoo**.

Here all the code for `sending messages`, `receiving messages` is given. You can import contacts and everything associated with it.

This library is in `java`. https://github.com/aldrinm/messenger-sdk