# Yahoo Messenger API For PHP

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-messenger

I've asked the same question before for Flex, but due to some restrictions, I'm gonna have to do all the communication from the back end.

I googled all day, I just can't find anything that works.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453206/anyone-know-yahoo-messenger-http-request) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for libpurple. It has [PHP bindings](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpurple).